# Difference between these two

Tags: java

I was trying to solve the problem on spoj but my answer is not accepting giving wrong answer i want to know difference between these two chunks of code.

Spoj accepting this

```
public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
      java.io.BufferedReader r = new java.io.BufferedReader(
            new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String s;
      while (!(s = r.readLine()).startsWith("42"))
         System.out.println(s);
   }
}
```

but Spoj not accepting this

```
 class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        new Test().universe();
    }

    public void universe() throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("Enter Number");
        java.util.Scanner scan = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        String input;
        while (!(input = scan.next()).startsWith("42")){
            System.out.println(input);
            }
        scan.close();

    }

}
```

here's the problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/TEST/

Comment: sorry for mistake i fixed the typo

Comment: First block of code re-formatted for readability.

Answer (score 1):

The first snippet reads the file line by line whereas the other one reads token by token. If there are more than one token per line, the result may be different.

Finally, both codes take the risk of reading the file without checking there is still something to read. In the first case it could throw a `NullPointerException` and in the second case a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: My answer explains it ! What makes no difference is reading from console of from whatever else.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that `scan.next()` is a blocking call - if there's no input, the call will wait until there is input.

You need to change your loop for the scanner to this:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    String input = scan.next();
    if (input.startsWith("42")) {
        System.out.println(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: scan.next(); is blocking what about r.readLine(); both return string

Comment: They will both block.

Comment: From the documentation of hasNext: "This method may block while waiting for input to scan."

Comment: that's what i was thinking

Answer (score 0):

Next is reading next token, maybe you meant nextLine.

Also, you are printing **"Enter number"** in the latter.